# Can I change a .mysql file to .sql or is it more complex than that?

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal

I am trying to migrate a Drupal site to a new host. In the tutorials I read I need an .sql export of the database, as well as the files (I have these). I don't have access to the old hosting phpmyadmin method but I used backup and migrate module on Drupal which created a file with .mysql extension.

After a few failed attempts at migrating, new host support says they need a .sql file

From what I see in my searches here, some have mentioned simply changing the extension of the file.

Can I just change the .mysql extension to .sql and give that to my new host - is it really that simple?

Comment: try to import that .mysql in your local environment and than try to export it using PHPMyadmin in .sql format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try back up & migrate module to import the file smoothly. .mysql file may not work if you try to import from phpmyadmin. Instead, install backup & migrate and then restore the db.

Comment: Can you explain why it may not work, what is the difference between a .mysql and .sql file? As I said in my answer, I'm not familiar with Drupal so if this module is necessary than I'll remove my answer.

Comment: As you said, you exported using 'back up & migrate' module. So, the db dump will work with that module. You need to install that module, and go to 'Restore' tab on module's configuration page.

Comment: So, in the end, I had my new host support doing this for me and they insisted I provide an .sql not .mysql. Changing the file extension and sending it to them wasn't acceptable. They worked it out and I also did manage to get an .sql from the old host. I believe the backup and migrate module would have worked if I had been able to take that route.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Drupal migrations but since mysql is sql the file probably contains just text (the sql). Changing the extension won't affect it's contents so it will be ok. Make a copy of the original file and change the extension of the copy to sql.

If the database you are migrating to is also mysql you just can import that file. What can go wrong is when you don't have enough permissions to import the file. You'll have to contact the hosting provider if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can just change it to SQL.

Every relational database server uses a SQL a bit different from the SQL standard, but usually they use the same extension: sql.